# Unable to run javascript for wordpress site using biz-news theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that used the toivo-lite theme and was able to load a custom javascript by editing the header.php under the toivo-lite theme folder, and then invoking the JS function through the body onload in that header.php file.  This worked like a charm.

Now this wordpress site has switched over to the biz-news theme, which in itself uses the agency-starter theme fwiu.  I edited the header.php under the biz-news theme folder the same way I did for the toivo-lite theme, but it did not work.  I also tried editing the header.php file under the agency-starter theme folder, but that did not work too.

I looked at the generated page but can not figure out what template / php file is being used in order to add my custom JS code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hit F12, go to console view to see errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here are plugins that helps you

[Insert Headers and Footers by WPBeginner](http://Insert%20Headers%20and%20Footers%20by%20WPBeginner) this plugin allow to add script or html code insert after body

[Show Current Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) this plugin show all template file load on current page